# (Android Studio) java.lang.NumberFormatException: s == null

Tags: java, android

So I'm getting the error  java.lang.NumberFormatException: s == null and I don't know why.. I posted a question earlier and it ended up being a typo, but for this one I think I can say that it's not.
If you need more info don't hesitate to say so. Thanks in advance!

Here's the full error code

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.example.flagquiz, PID: 3343

java.lang.NumberFormatException: s == null
    
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:577)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
    at com.example.flagquiz.MainActivityFragment.updateGuessRows(MainActivityFragment.java:104)
    at com.example.flagquiz.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:65)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8018)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3475)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

and here's the affected code:

MainActivity:

```
      protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();

        if(preferencesChanged){
            MainActivityFragment quizFragment = (MainActivityFragment)
                    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                            R.id.quizFragment);

            result = quizFragment;

            quizFragment.updateGuessRows(
                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));
            quizFragment.updateRegions(
                    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));
            quizFragment.resetQuiz();
            preferencesChanged = false;
        }
    }
```

And MainActivityFragment:

```
public void updateGuessRows(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences){
        String choices =
                sharedPreferences.getString(MainActivity.CHOICE, null);
        guessRows = Integer.parseInt(choices) / 2;

        for(LinearLayout layout : guessLinearLayouts)
            layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        for(int row = 0; row < guessRows; row++)
            guessLinearLayouts[row].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: can you share what makes you think that `sharedPreferences.getString(MainActivity.CHOICE, null);` should not return null?

Comment: Use `.putInt()` and `.getInt()` instead, then no casting is required at all.

Answer (score 0):

The exception message tells us that at the line `guessRows = Integer.parseInt(choices) / 2;` the variable `choices` must be null.

You read that value in the line before:

```
String choices = sharedPreferences.getString(MainActivity.CHOICE, null);
```

This line can only set `choices` to `null` if there is no key `MainActivity.CHOICE`.

Instead of using a default value of `null` you probably should use "0" as default value:

```
String choices = sharedPreferences.getString(MainActivity.CHOICE, "0");
```

---

But, as Martin Zeitler has noted in his comment: if your preference value is a number value that fits in the range of the `int` data type it is better to store it as `int` value in the shared preferences.

That would allow to replace

```
    String choices = sharedPreferences.getString(MainActivity.CHOICE, null);
    guessRows = Integer.parseInt(choices) / 2;
```

with

```
    guessRows = sharedPreferences.getInt(MainActivity.CHOICE, 0) / 2;
```